# How to move MySQL 5.6 server data to another one not depending on dump command?

Tags: mysql

I installed Windows 10 yesterday and couldn't back up my MySQL database with admin commands. But Windows 10 installation didn't remove the old files. So I can access the old MySQL server directory with those files. Is there any way to move data moving files to the new MySQL's directories?

For more information, I am using MySQL 5.7 server and the previous version was 5.6. But If there is a way, I can downgrade the new version to 5.6.

Comment: What did you use to install your WAMP Stack? WAMPServer, XAMPP, IIS, Installed from individual part, something else,

Comment: Of course the obvius option would be install the same MYSQL5.6.x and do the backup you forgot to do before installing W10

Comment: Just I installed mysql server only and I have another client tool to access it. that's all

Comment: @RiggsFolly you mean..  I install same version and move all old files in to the directories of new one?

Comment: If the files are still there, you should be able to uninstall the MYSQL Service **(Just the service)** from MYSQL5.7, reinstall the service from the MYSQL5.6 folders, do a backup, then reverse the process

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ok I will try!

Comment: Make sure you have a backup of all your MYSQL5.6 folder, you may need to have more than one try at this

Comment: @RiggsFolly One more thing. I can't find the data files that I want to recover in mysql directories. Does mysql have any other directories to save the schema files?

Comment: by default mysql saves databases in the `\mysql\data\` folder. Look in the `my.ini`or `my.cnf` file to see if they have been config's to be saved somewhere else for `datadir=` What table types were you using? MYISAM or INNODB

Comment: @RiggsFolly I looked every cnf/ini files in old directories. but there was no modification about the data directory. but I can't not find the schema data. Is there any possible directories remained?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121704/discussion-between-riggsfolly-and-verystrongjoe).